# How to Calculate Scale Factor if Screen Resolution Will Change in AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4

If i change the screen resolution then, how I will calculate the Change Scale Factor of an object :

For example my object current this.scaleX is 0.8 , this.scaleY is 0.8 (as you know scaleX and scaleY are the properties of the Flex) and my current screen resolution is 1360*768

Now I change the screen resolution to 800*600 ,

Then how I will calculate the changed scaleX and scaleY of my object.

I am using the following formula to find the changed/updated Scale Factor :

```
scaleX = scaleX * (768 / 1360) * (800 / 600);

scaleY = scaleY * (768 / 1360) * (800 / 600);
```

But it is not giving Correct result to me,

So please Help me to solve this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To calculate the scale of an axis you only need to take into account the values of that axis on the screen. So either X (width) or Y (height), but not both. Also I would use the width and height of the screen at a scale of 1 as reference values. This will make it easier to calculate the new scale. In your case:

```
screenWidthAtFullScale = 1360 / 0.8
screenHeightAtFullScale = 768 / 0.8
scaleX = 800 / screenWidthAtFullScale => 0.47
scaleY = 600 / screenHeightAtFullScale => 0.625
```

Note that this will distort your object. It would be better to calculate one scale and apply that to both the X and Y axis to prevent that.

Comment: Thank you for a great answer!!! But how i know in which case i will take scaleX and in which case i will take scaleY Because in the above case scaleX is my correct answer but in some cases scaleY is the correct answer.

Comment: This totally depends on your screen. I can imaginge that in some cases scaling to X instead of Y will yield better results. Why not take the smallest scaling factor after you calculated both of them, that might perhaps be a good option.